# Hexadecimal representation

Tags: c, hex

I'd like to print hexadecimal int value as %d.

When value is written as hexadecimal it's not a problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        int x=0x18;
        int y=0xAB;
        printf("%d %d", x, y );

        return 0;
    }
```

But... How can I print when this is dec value ?

I would like something like this:

1. Value in decimal:

x = 551 change to hex x = 227 and print as %d ?

In this exercise I must print hex integer as %d.

Hope I write this clean. :)

Regards,

Comment: `x` and `y` are not "hex integers". They're just integers.

Comment: read the man page of printf

Comment: Are you trying to *convert* to hex representation and then print the resulting string or are you asking for what format specifier to use for to print an int in hex? If the former -- implement a base-conversion algorithm. If the later -- read the manual (or spend 30 seconds on Google). In either case --- I don't know what you mean by "print using %d" since that specifier prints in decimal, not hex. If you construct the hex string then you would need `%s` to display it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Odd request: to print the value in decimal, using `"%x"`.

```
void dec_print_with_x(unsigned x) {
  if (x >= 10) dec_print_with_x(x/10);
  printf("%x", x%10);
}

int main ( void )
{
  dec_print_with_x(0x227);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
551
```

To be clear, a variable `x` like `int x = 0x227;` or `int x = 551;` is neither, decimal, hexadecimal nor binary.  It has an integer *value* encoded somehow and stored somewhere - most likely as a fixed-width pattern of bits in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

`0x18`, `0xAB` `0x227` are *text* that is part of the source code and `"551"` as part of the output.  These sequences of characters denote a value in hexadecimal or decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
int x = 898;
x = 0x382;
printf(" x = %d", x);
```

The output will be:

```
 x = 898
```

In your code, `898` and `0x382` are two different ways of representing the same number.  They're stored exactly the same way.

What `printf` does is take the internal representation of that number and print it in decimal format if you use `%d` or hexadecimal format if you use `%x`.  How you do the assignment doesn't matter.

Another way of looking at it -- This code:

```
int x = 898;
int y = 0x382;
if (x == y) {
    printf("x and y are equal\n");
} else {
    printf("x and y are not equal\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
x and y are equal
```